# Most Efficient Way to Compare String Dates in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

We have a PostgreSQL DB running on AWS (Engine Version 11.8).
For each item, we are storing dates as strings [varchar type] (in the following format - '2020-12-16')
Our app has requirements to do date range queries. Based on that, what is the best and most efficient way to do string date comparisons in PostgreSQL?
I looked at several questions here on SO, but no one talks about the question if there is a difference to store the dates as type "varchar" or type "date".
Also based on the 2 storage types above, what would be the most efficient way to do queries? In particular we are looking at querying for ranges (for example from '2020-12-10' and '2020-12-16')
Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: "*we are storing dates as strings*" - why, oh why? Don't do that, ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> no one talks about the question if there is a difference to store the dates as type "varchar" or type "date".

Fix your data model! You should be using the proper datatype to store your data: dates should be stored as `date`. Using the wrong datatype is wrong for many reasons:

- whenever you need to do date arithmetic, you need to convert your strings to a date (eg: how do you add one month to *string* `'2020-12-16'`?); this is highly inefficient
- data integrity cannot be enforced at the time when your data is stored; even using check constraints is not enough. Eg: how can you tell whether `'2021-02-29'` is a valid date or not?

> what would be the most efficient way to do queries? In particular we are looking at querying for ranges.

That said, the format that you are using makes it possible to do direct string comparison. So for a simple range comparison, I would suggest string operations:

```
where mystring >= '2020-12-10' and mystring < '2020-12-16'
```

Comment: ok this means use date type + use >= and < ? That direct string comparison internally would do type conversions and do efficient querying i assume? @GMB

Comment: @AleksandarT The operators that can be used depend on the data types. (again a good reason to use the `DATE` type)

Comment: Do you think BETWEEN would have any performance differences?

Comment: Comparing `date` will be cheaper, because that is an integer comparison. Comparing strings has to iterate through the characters, and unless you specify the `C` collation (which you should), you'll get expensive locale sensitive comparisons.

Comment: Plus; it will be very hard to estimate week days, or week numbers.

Comment: One more question, would the timezones matter?  For example if i insert '2020-12-10' this is without time. But on DB level i wonder if it would matter?

Comment: But String dates comparison doesn't work properly. For example, `'12/08/2022' > '06/09/2022'` returns `true` which it shouldn't. Better way if dataset cannot be changed is to use `to_date(date, format)`.

Answer (score 0):

Before even thinking about performance: use the correct data types.

Try, for instance, to get all the `friday the thirteenth` in 2020 with your string representation. With dates it is very easy:

---

```
CREATE table thisyear(
        thedate DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

INSERT INTO thisyear(thedate)
SELECT generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2021-01-01'::date -1, '1 day'::interval)
        ;

SELECT * FROM thisyear
WHERE date_part('dow', thedate) = 5 -- friday
AND date_part('day', thedate) = 13  -- the thirteenth
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 366
  thedate   
------------
 2020-03-13
 2020-11-13
(2 rows)
```